# Basic question in trainable parameters in CNN convolution

Tags: keras, filter, parameters, conv-neural-network

I am learning CNN trainable parameters calculation in Keras.  I just wonder why we consider filter calculation as trainable parameters?  Since the convolution process is a fixed calculation (i.e. matrix multiplication) and there are nothing need to update (trainable).  I know there is a formula but why we consider this as trainable parameters.  For example:  in the first conV2D, image size, say 10x10x1, filter 3 x 3 , 1 filter, the parameters in keras is 10 (3x3+1).

Alex

Comment: You completely misunderstood how convolution works in CNNs.

Answer (score 0):

In your convolution layer there is a 3x3(x1) kernel (the x1 since your image only has a single channel).  The values in the convolution layer's kernel are *learned* parameters.  In addition to the kernel itself, the convolution layer (may, it's usually optional) have a learnable bias parameter (that's the +1 in your formula).  It's a bit hard to understand from your question, but it looks like in your setup you are asking the layer to learn the parameters for 10 different convolutional kernels (each with a bias) hence the 10(3x3+1) learned parameters.